Repeatedly getting wrong answer solving exponential equation
I have an equation I'm trying to solve:
$2^{3x+1}-2^{x-1}=16$
I know from brute force that $x \approx 1.03$
However, when I actually try to solve the equation, I never get that as an answer.
Trying to take the log of each side:
$log_{2}(2^{3x + 1}) - log_{2}(2^{x-1}) = log_{2}(16)$
$(3x + 1)log_2(2) - (x - 1)log_2(2) = log_2$
$(3x + 1)(1) - (x - 1)(1) = 4$
$3x + 1 - x + 1 = 4$
$2x + 2 = 4$
$2x = 2$
$x = 1$
Or trying to get all terms to have the same base:
$2^{3x+1} - 2^{x-1} = 2^4$
$(3x + 1) - (x - 1) = 4$
$3x + 1 - x + 1 = 4$
$2x + 2 = 4$
$2x = 2$
$x = 1$
I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm just not sure what.

The property of logs is $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ not $\log(a+b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$, so these approaches are not productive. The usual trick here is to let $y=2^x$ and consider what the equation looks like after this substitution.

In fact, given what you know about the expected solution value the substitution $y=2^{x-1}$ may be more appropriate. It's a minor point but may make the result cleaner.

@Semiclassical - that is a nice idea, although since the answer here is irrational I'm not sure there is much gained. If there was known to be a rational (or better, integer) result this substitution would be much more efficient.

@RedFive Agreed---I hadn't noticed it was a cubic equation at the time.

The $3x$ in the power was the clue for me.

This is actually a disguised cubic equation.
$2^{3x+1}-2^{x-1}=16$
$2\times 2^{3x}-\frac{1}{2}\times 2^x=16$
$4\times 2^{3x}-2^x=32$
Now, let $u=2^x$, then the equation becomes $4u^3-u=32$ or $4u^3-u-32=0$
Solving for $u$ (Updated) gives only one real solution: $u\approx 2.04166$
Which leads to $x=\log_{2}{2.5859}\approx 1.0297$

Interesting. I will check my work. Thanks. Update yes, found my error. I used 2 instead of 4 as the lead coefficient. Will update now. Much appreciated.


Trying to take the log of each side:
$$\log_{2}(2^{3x + 1}) - \log_{2}(2^{x-1}) = \log_{2}(16)$$

That's not how logarithm works. $\log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab)$, not $\log(a+b)$
You have to solve by letting $2^x = t$, where $t > 0$ then solve the cubic equation
